# Java or Actionscript for audio/video recording and p2p, what's better?

Tags: java, actionscript

What is better to study. Java or Actionscript for audio & video recording and streaming.

And working with p2p.

Can java stream video/audio via p2p?

Thanks ;)

Comment: There's only one way to find out..   FIGHT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionScript has simple classes with well defined protocols designed specifically for accessing a machines audio and video devices. With flash 10.0, there is support for direct p2p connections with other machines, and with 10.1, support for p2p mesh networks. See the code example here for out of the box audio/video/p2p: [ActionScript 3.0 Reference - NetGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can access the sound system (input and output) using [Java Sound](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html), and you can stream it over a socket. You'll probably want compression, and if you want that to be MP3 you'll also need [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html).

I don't know about video in Java, nor do I really know the options of Flash/AIR in this area.